# Hexadecimal to decimal conversion formula

Tags: java, hex, decimal, formula

From the book
"Introduction to Java Programming, Comprehensive Version 10th Edition - Daniel Liang" Chapter 6, page 217.

From the text below I'm having trouble understanding the formula for hex to decimal conversions.

> h<sub>n</sub> * 16<sup>n</sup> + h<sub>n-1</sub> * 16<sup>n-1</sup> + h<sub>n-2</sub> * 16<sup>n-2</sup> + ... + h<sub>2</sub> * 16<sup>2</sup> + h<sub>1</sub> * 16<sup>1</sup> + h<sub>0</sub> * 16<sup>0</sup>
>
> For example, the hex number AB8C is
>
> 10 * 16<sup>3</sup> + 11 * 16<sup>2</sup> + 8 * 16<sup>1</sup> + 12 * 16<sup>0</sup> = 43916

I understand the second part of the formula and how the answer in the given example was arrived at, but not the first part

> h<sub>n</sub> * 16<sup>n</sup> + h<sub>n-1</sub> * 16<sup>n-1</sup> + h<sub>n-2</sub> * 16<sup>n-2</sup> +

why the subtraction of the hex numbers and powers?
In the example given the subtraction isn't done, so what's it for?

Thank you for your help.

I'm unsure what is meant by my question being unclear given T.J. Crowder was able to provide an answer that cleared up my confusion.
I thought the wording of the question quite clearly articulated what my problem was.
I'm new here so I might be missing something obvious?
Am I supposed to accept an answer?

Never mind, just noticed the tick mark near the answer.

Comment: That is basic math. It is not subtraction of numbers but indexes. n represents index.

Comment: You could probably ask this in Mathematics section of stackexchange and meanwhile checkout: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Comment: @Smit Thanks for the link. I know how to convert hex to decimal, it was just understanding the formula that was throwing me off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subtraction *is* done in the example, in the exponent: *n* is the number of digits in the hex number minus one. So for instance, for AB8C, *n* is 3. What the formula is saying is that:

- You multiply A by 16 raised to ***n***, e.g. `0xA * 16^3`
- You multiply B by 6 raised to ***n-1***, e.g. `0xB * 16^2`
- You multiply 8 by 6 raised to ***n-2***, e.g. `0x8 * 16^1`
- You multiply C by 6 raised to ***n-3***, e.g. `0xC * 16^0`
- You add those results together

So if you were writing code to convert hex to decimal, you'd need to have an *n* and a loop, and decrement *n* on each loop.

Comment: Thanks. Made it just that little bit clearer for me to understand.